# How do I append a list to another list that is dependent on a variable to create a nested list?

Tags: python

```
def list_size(size)
 alist1 = []
 alist2 = size * [' ',' ',' ']
```

say my variable(size) is 2 I need to create a nested list of `[[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]`. This nested list varies depending on what is put in for the variable in `list size()`

not sure how to create a function to set

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please emphasize what is the problem with your current function

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def makeList(a,b):
    return([a]*b)

print(makeList([" "," "," "," "], 2))
```

```
[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

Comment: I think `a` is constant, though

Comment: idk i felt wrong to assume that :/

Comment: Note that multiplying the arrays like this will actually multiple the references and not duplicate the array, which I think is not what the questioner is intending

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make this to complicated. In the end you just want multiple array

```py
def list_size(size)
    return [[' ',' ',' '] for _ in range(size)]
```

This uses a list comprehension together with `range` to create the appropriate amount. I don't like multiplying array since that will create duplicate references which (most of the time) is not what people want.